# What are all the commands for singleplayer minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to know all the commands for singleplayer minecraft without mods

Answer (score 1):

> Commands may be used by players, operators and the Command Block while in multiplayer connected to a Minecraft server, and in **singleplayer when the user has cheats enabled for the world.**

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Operator-only_commands

Comment: I mean not on a server

Comment: You can use those commands in singleplayer but you need to enable cheat. Without mod, there is no other command. What kind of command do you need ?